# How im get cookies on a Server side component in Next.js 13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, next.js, axios

```
import axios from "axios";

const Api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
});

axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = cookie;
```

document.cookie doesn't work in server side.

Some way to get cookie or passing cookies by props

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a simple way to do it in Server Components with cookies from next:

```
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

const myCookie = cookies().get("cookieName").value;
```